# What's does "${host%%-*} mean in configure file?

Tags: shell, configure

There is a following line in `configure`:

```
host_cpu="${host%%-*}"
```

But how to understand this line? How the `host` variable are parsed？Is there any tutorials about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It removes all the material after a dash in the value of the `$host` variable.  The double `%%` means the longest string that matches the `-*` which follows.  See the Bash manual on [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more details.

For example, given:

```
host="preliminary-name.sub-domain.domain.com"
echo "${host%%-*}"
```

the output will be `preliminary`.  By contrast, a single `%` would yield `preliminary-name.sub`.